# Error running RubyGems plugin when trying to run the gem command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm getting this error when trying to run the `gem` command. Does anyone know what is causing this? It's causing me to be not able to run `rails g migration` commands (I get a similar error), and I'd imagine probably a lot more.

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/storwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": undefined method `stubs' for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError)
/Users/storwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:255:in `matching_specs': undefined method `stubs' for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError)
from /Users/storwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:279:in `to_specs'
from /Users/storwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
from /Users/storwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
from /Users/storwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:572:in `load_yaml'
from /Users/storwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:327:in `load_file'
from /Users/storwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:196:in `initialize'
from /Users/storwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new'
from /Users/storwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `do_configuration'
from /Users/storwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run'
from /Users/storwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Update: I've also tried the `rake` command and it throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found an older link related to the [same problem](https://gist.github.com/Wayneoween/2383354)
, and it seems that it might be either a (1) Ruby installation issue, or (2) RubyGem issue. If it a Ruby issue, you need to uninstall and reinstall Ruby by using RVM (Ruby Version Manager) it seems that it worked for some. If it's  (2) RubyGem issue (which it probably is), you either have to delete '/Users/storwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.2.2/' folder or change the content in rubygems_plugin.rb file.

One of the users suggested (you can find from the link): 
*"When I use "gem -v", the response will give me the error "Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/mercury/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-0.2.8/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- rubygems_bundler/rubygems_bundler_installer (LoadError)
So I edit "rubygems_plugins.rb", and I change the require path of rubygems_bundler, the path after modified is "./rubygems_bundler/{file_name}", and the problem solved."*

I hope these instructions + link will help you to solve the problem. I did go through the same tutorial book by Michael Hartl last summer. I think I have encountered a similar issue. I think I might have deleted one folder in order solve the issue, and perhaps reinstalled something as well (but I am not 100% because it has been a while) .

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

$gem update --system